# Can I use CSS assets and the public folder in the same app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a legacy application that I'd like to migrate to use the Rails 3 asset pipeline. I have upwards of 100 stylesheets which are imported on a template by template basis using a

```
content_for :stylesheets
```

block.

Compiling them all into a single stylesheet is not currently a goer as the code was written to expect only certain stylesheets on certain pages, so for example the login page imports a stylesheet which redefines *article form*. It would not be good to redefine this on all pages.

Is there a way to migrate slowly to the assets pipeline having the app look first for a **compiled asset**, and then having it failover to the **public/stylesheets** directory?

Comment: might be you can add to config for precompiled css,

Comment: I had thought about making a huge array and precompiling all the assets, but it doesn't feel like the right way to go about things...

Comment: Ok,might be you can put into public/stylesheet directory and<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheet/abc.css" %> see if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this "right", one thing that would not take a huge amount of effort would be to put a class name on your `<html>` or `<body>` tag and wrap the contents of your CSS files with a selector. For example, I use something similar to the following in my `ApplicationController`.

```
before_filter :body_class

def body_class
  controller_name = self.class.name.gsub(/Controller$/, '')
  if !controller_name.index('::').nil?
    namespace, controller_name = controller_name.split('::')
  end

  @body_classes = ["#{controller_name.underscore}_#{action_name} ".downcase.strip]
  @body_classes = ["#{namespace.underscore}_#{@default_body_classes.join}".strip] if !namespace.nil?
end
```

Then, in my layout I have something similar to this

```
<body class="<%= @default_body_classes.join(' ') %>">
```

Next, you could change the extension for all of your stylesheets to `.css.scss`. Put them all in the new `app/assets/stylesheets` directory. To include them quickly *(though possibly out of order)*, add

```
/*
 * =require_tree .
 */
```

to the top of a new `app/assets/application.css.scss` file. Just include this one `application.css` file in your layouts.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => 'screen' %>
```

Finally, spend some time going through your stylesheets wrapping the entirety of each document with the appropriate body class. For example, if you have a stylesheet specific to some `User::Admin` controller's `signup` action, you would wrap the entirety of that stylesheet with

```
.user_admin.signup {
  /* Your stylesheet's content here */
}
```

Sass will prefix all nested content properly with the `.user_admin.signup` class that will be appended to your `<body>` tag when that action's being rendered.

I realize this isn't really an intermediate fix as you're looking for, but following steps similar to this you should be able to get 95% of the way there with not much effort, and it will be done "right".